# No such file or directory (opendir) PHP

Tags: php, opendir, readdir

I have a problem with my `opendir` function.

```
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

I checked if my folder exists and it does. I chmodded the permissions to **777**. What could be the problem?

For example: `images/car/Volvo_S40_4dr_sedan/`

Doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: check `getcwd()` if using relative paths

Comment: Check relative path... are you sure that PHP's working directory is where you think it is?

Comment: First step would be to inspect the result of `file_exists($dir)` and then `is_dir($dir)` and then `realpath($dir)`. And check if you're running on some ancient PHP install with safe mode enabled.

Comment: It's the correct directory and safe mode is disabled..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using relative paths. If so then make sure you correctly construct the path relative to your script's current working directory.

To troubleshoot assign an absolute path to `$dir`, eg. `$dir = "/var/www/myproject/images/car/Volvo_S40_4dr_sedan/"`. If it works then the cause of the problem is a bad reference of relative path.

I would recommend you to stick with absolute paths unless you have a good reason to use relative paths.